# Equalities of Integrals with simple expressions

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

I'm trying to understand why the following equalities are correct:

1. The integral of ($sinx - {\frac{2}{\pi}})^2 $ from $0$ to $\pi$ is exactly the same as the integral $(sinx - {\frac{2}{\pi}}) \times sinx$ from $0$ to $\pi$.
2. The integral of ($x^2 - x + {\frac{1}{6}})^2 $ from $0$ to $1$ is exactly the same as the integral $(x^2 - x + {\frac{1}{6}}) \times x^2$ from $0$ to $1$.

Can you please help me to understand why these equalities are true?

Thank you in advance,

Syndicator.